# Visual Studio community installation problem

Tags: visual-studio, installation, window

Every time I want to install Visual Studio I get this error message I can't find anything on the internet to solve this. You can see the screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8xQI.png)

fr:
Visual Studio lnstaller
Impossible de lancer le programme d'installation Erreur : L'élément
a déjà été ajouté, clé du dirtionnaire 'C:\Windows\System32' clé
aoutée 'C\WINDOWS\System32'

en:
Visual Studio installer unable to launch installer Error: Item has already been added, dirtionnaire key 'C:\Windows\System32' added key 'C\WINDOWS\System32'

Comment: Hi Valoon, do you have any updates? Please close the Visual Studio Installer and delete the Visual Studio Installer directory. Typically, the directory is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer. After that, run the Visual Studio Installer bootstrapper file as administrator to to install, if this issue persists, please feel free to let us know.

Comment: Hi, I already try this and it didn’t work

Comment: Thanks for your update, would you please share us your setup log file so that we can conduct further research?
You could get the log files with the Collect.exe tool https://aka.ms/vscollect :
1. Please save the executable file to your local folder if you want to use it later or you could run the executable file directly.
2. Double click the Collect.exe and the tool will collect the log file automatically.
3. The Pop window will be closed automatically after collecting logs finish.
4. And then it will create a compressed cabinet of all the VS and .NET logs to %TEMP%\vslogs.zip.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run [this troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d) when you run visual studio installer.

If it doesn't work, please follow this document: [Troubleshoot Visual Studio installation and upgrade issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2019)